# Getting a class to act as a tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a class act in every way like a tuple that's an attribute of the class, so len(instance) would be the same as len(instance.tup), instance[3] would return instance.tup[3], etc. Here's the class:

```
class mytup(object):
     def __init__(self, a):
         self.tup = tuple(a)
     def __getattr__(self, nm):
         f = types.MethodType(lambda self:getattr(self.tup, nm)(), self, type(self))
         f.__func__.func_name = nm
         setattr(self, nm, f)
         return f
```

I can

```
mt = mytup(range(10))
```

But if I try to:

```
In [253]: len(mt)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-253-67688b907b8a> in <module>()
----> 1 len(mt)

TypeError: object of type 'mytup' has no len()
```

mt does in fact have a __len__ that I can call:

```
In [254]: mt.__len__
Out[254]: <bound method mytup.__len__ of <__main__.mytup object at 0x2e85150>>
In [255]: mt.__len__()
Out[255]: 10
```

(I even renamed it __len__). As near as I can tell, this should look just as if I did:

```
def __len__(self, *a):
    return self.tup.__len__(*a)
```

But python won't let me len(mt) (or mt[2] or mt [1:5] for that matter).

Comment: Just a question, why do you need this?

Comment: why don't you inherit everything from the `tuple` class then?

Comment: Can you just use a `namedtuple` from the collections module?

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Heck, why aren't you just using a tuple? The best way to get something that behaves in every way like a tuple is to use a tuple.

Comment: I've left out parts. I want to create a class that for all intents and purposes looks and acts as a tuple, but the data therein comes from some other source (and indeed can change behind the scenes via other methods). This is why I can't just subclass tuple (or use a tuple, for that matter).

Comment: @mlv to do this probably want to use meta-classes. That just seems crazy, though, because you basically want inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working as you have hoped is because doing:

```
setattr(self, nm, f)
```

Is *not equivalent* to

```
def __len__(self, *a):
    return self.tup.__len__(*a)
```

In the latter case, your method is a property of *the class* because it is defined in *class scope*. It would be the equivlanet of `setattr(cls, nm, f)`. If you check `MyTup.__dict__` you will see it there. However, in the former case, `__len__` is a property of the *instance*. So it will be in `my_instance.__dict__`. `len` checks the class for a `__len__` method, and doesn't find one. Hence the error. Your `__getattr__` is never actually called, and even if it were, it wouldn't allow you to use `len`. You *can* use `an_instanec.__len__` diretly, though.

Comment: Thanks. That explains why it's failing. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: @mlv don't try to reinvent inheritance? Use a `nametuple`? I don't know. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I assumed you were trying to figure out more about Python internals. Why not inherit from `tuple`?

Comment: Yes, I do want to learn more about python internals. That's the main thing that drove this Quixotic quest. That and not wanting to define wrapper methods for every tuple method.

Comment: I ended up just defining 6 methods, `__hash__`, `__repr__`, `__cmp__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, and `__getitem__` (probably didn't need `__iter__`, but it made things faster).

Answer (score 3):

New-style classes look-up "special methods"—those that start and end with two underscore characters—on an instance's *class* not the instance involved, so when `len()` is called it tries to call `typeof(mt).__len__()`. So the proper way to do what you want would be to use one of the [Abstract Base Classes for Containers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) in the `collections` module (since Python 3.3)

```
import collections.abc

class MyTuple(collections.abc.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.tup = tuple(a)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.tup)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.tup[index]

mt = MyTuple(range(10))
print(len(mt))  # -> 10
print(mt[4])  # -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`len` does not use `__getattr__` to get the `__len__` function - it calls `__len__` directly.

Calling **`x.__len__`** is like calling `getattr(x, '__len__')` - which will return the `x.__len__` method object.

**`len`** works behind the scene, so it can access this method directly, without invoking the `__getattr__` helper.

- Try to add a print statement in your `__getattr__` to see what is printed when calling `len` (hint: nothing).